# I couldnt get the joined table value in my query

Tags: codeigniter

[Workflow type table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgezu.png)

```
 [Workflow caterory table][2]


public function view_wf_category()
{
            $this->db->select('workflow_category.wf_cat','workflow_type.type_name');
            $this->db->from('workflow_category');
            $this->db->join('workflow_type', 'workflow_type.workflow_type_id = workflow_category.wf_type');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            foreach($query->result_array() AS $row)
            {
                echo $row["wf_cat"]."<br/>";
                echo $row["type_name"]."<br/>";
            }

}
```

here im not able to print the  $row["type_name"] and also showing a notice as undefined index for $row["type_name"].

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
public function view_wf_category()
{
            $this->db->select('workflow_category.wf_cat,workflow_type.type_name')
                   ->from('workflow_category')
                   ->join('workflow_type', 'workflow_type.workflow_type_id = workflow_category.wf_type');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
            {
                echo $row["wf_cat"]."<br/>";
                echo $row["type_name"]."<br/>";
            }

}
```

Error due to this line..

```
$this->db->select('workflow_category.wf_cat','workflow_type.type_name');
```

So it should be just

```
$this->db->select('workflow_category.wf_cat,workflow_type.type_name');
```

In above query i have been used query grouping.